# automatically run a method in java web application

Tags: java, web

How would I write a web application in Java that starts a method with a period of one hour (without client request).

For example, it might automatically read a web page every hour.

Comment: Do you want to run a scheduled Job every one hr ?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to run a method (scheduled) from server side

Comment: I edited the question to standardize the jargon. I also split it into paragraphs to make it a little more readable. I removed the conclusion because on Stack Overflow we like to keep posts as directed and concise as possible.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview.

Answer (score 1):

I implement a `ServletContextListener` and on `contextInitialized` I use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to `scheduleWithFixedDelay` a `Runnable` that performs the task.  Add a `@WebListener` annotation to the class and it all starts up automagically.

Answer (score 0):

You may use TimerTask to achieve the goal:

First define a class that extends TimerTask, and write what you want to do inside the run() method.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class DateTask extends TimerTask {   
    @ Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Current Time ：" + new Date());
    }
}
```

Then in another class, use schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) to set the period of the method.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;

public class TimerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerDemo timerDemo = new TimerDemo();
        timerDemo.testScheduleDelayAndPeriod();
    }

    void testScheduleDelayAndPeriod() {      
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        System.out.println("Period： 2 seconds");
        System.out.println("In testScheduleDelayAndPeriod："  + new Date());

        timer.schedule(new DateTask(), 0, 2000);  
  }
}
```

Here is the result of the code I wrote:

```
Period： 2 seconds
In testScheduleDelayAndPeriod：Mon Mar 23 11:42:52 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:42:52 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:42:54 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:42:56 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:42:58 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:43:00 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:43:02 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:43:04 CST 2015
Current Time ：Mon Mar 23 11:43:06 CST 2015
```

It prints the current time every 2 seconds.